# Scroll TTreeView while dragging over/near the edges

Tags: delphi, treeview, scroll

I have a TTreeView that can have lots of nodes, when a lot of nodes are expanded the tree uses a lot of screen space.

Now suppose I want to drag a node that is near the bottom of the TreeView to the top, I can't physically see the top part of the TreeView because the node I am selecting is at the bottom. When dragging the node to the top of the TreeView I would like the TreeView to automatically scroll with me when dragging, by default this does not seem  to happen.

A perfect example of this behaviour is seen in Windows Explorer. If you try to drag a file or folder, when you hover the dragged item (node) it automatically scrolls up or down depending on cursor position.

Hope that makes sense.

PS, I already know how to drag nodes, I want the TreeView to scroll with me when dragging if hovering near the top or bottom of the TreeView.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the code I use. It will work for any `TWinControl` descendent: list box, tree view, list view etc.

```
type
  TAutoScrollTimer = class(TTimer)
  private
    FControl: TWinControl;
    FScrollCount: Integer;
    procedure InitialiseTimer;
    procedure Timer(Sender: TObject);
  public
    constructor Create(Control: TWinControl);
  end;

{ TAutoScrollTimer }

constructor TAutoScrollTimer.Create(Control: TWinControl);
begin
  inherited Create(Control);
  FControl := Control;
  InitialiseTimer;
end;

procedure TAutoScrollTimer.InitialiseTimer;
begin
  FScrollCount := 0;
  Interval := 250;
  Enabled := True;
  OnTimer := Timer;
end;

procedure TAutoScrollTimer.Timer(Sender: TObject);

  procedure DoScroll;
  var
    WindowEdgeTolerance: Integer;
    Pos: TPoint;
  begin
    WindowEdgeTolerance := Min(25, FControl.Height div 4);
    GetCursorPos(Pos);
    Pos := FControl.ScreenToClient(Pos);
    if not InRange(Pos.X, 0, FControl.Width) then begin
      exit;
    end;
    if Pos.Y<WindowEdgeTolerance then begin
      SendMessage(FControl.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEUP, 0);
    end else if Pos.Y>FControl.Height-WindowEdgeTolerance then begin
      SendMessage(FControl.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEDOWN, 0);
    end else begin
      InitialiseTimer;
      exit;
    end;

    if FScrollCount<50 then begin
      inc(FScrollCount);
      if FScrollCount mod 5=0 then begin
        //speed up the scrolling by reducing the timer interval
        Interval := MulDiv(Interval, 3, 4);
      end;
    end;

    if Win32MajorVersion<6 then begin
      //in XP we need to clear up transient "fluff"; results in flickering so only do it in XP where it is needed
      FControl.Invalidate;
    end;
  end;

begin
  if Mouse.IsDragging then begin
    DoScroll;
  end else begin
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

Then to use it you add an `OnStartDrag` event handler for the control and implement it like this:

```
procedure TMyForm.SomeControlStartDrag(Sender: TObject; var DragObject: TDragObject);
begin
  TAutoScrollTimer.Create(Sender as TWinControl);
end;
```

Comment: @Craig I edited it a bit to remove some of the code that was specific to my app. But in any case I think the basic idea is clear enough.

Comment: @David thanks for fast reply, what am I doing wrong though. I added Math to uses clause, defined FScrollCount : integer as global variable, ScaleFromSmallFontsDimension() does not work as you said may be the case, so I tried replacing with: MulDiv(Mouse.CursorPos.X, Screen.PixelsPerInch, 96); I put that code in a TTimer, when scrolling the tree sometimes moves backwords when it should go up. I think I entered something wrong

Comment: @Craig I've updated the answer to hopefully make things a bit clearer. FScrollCount should be a private variable of the form rather than a global, not that it really matters all that much, it's just better practice. ScaleFromSmallFontsDimension is just a way to take a dimensions in pixels and make it scale when the user has font scaling active. I've added a naive implementation. You could simply use a hard-coded value of 25 pixels, say. I bet nobody would ever notice if you wrote `WindowEdgeTolerance := 25` rather than my version.

Comment: @David thanks for posting back with updated code, I will check this out soon... EDIT, work perfect thanks David very useful code I would not of even known how to implement this.

Comment: You might want to add some "margin" to the detection bounds, say 50 pixels around the ListView, to make it feel more like a scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have since changed it from 25 to 50

Comment: Wait a minute, have you got a procedure in a procedure in a procedure here? Didn't notice it the first time. I often find myself in a position like that when it seems more logical to put certain procs/functions, like matryoshkas, inside one another but it's very seldom that I actually do that. So my question is, what is the practical benefit of doing so?

Comment: @Andriy Motivation for local procedures is no different from the normal motivation for breaking code up into smaller composable parts. The downside for local procedures are that they have more complex scoping rules (they can see the locals in any outer procedures). This means that you should use them with a deal of care and avoid nesting beyond the first level if possible.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I actually have no problem with using local procedures in general. It's just that I rarely nest my sub-routines deeper than one level. And the main concern for me here is readability. Presently, in cases when a proc C is logically local to a proc B, which, in turn, is local to a proc A, I almost always declare them like this: `proc A; { proc C { body_of_C } proc B { body_of_B } body_of_A }` rather than like this: `proc A { proc B { proc C { body_of_C } body_of_B } body_of_A }`. When writing code, deep nesting may seem natural, but later turns out harder to analyse.

Comment: +1^ @David - Thank you for this great piece of code. I truly believe you should write a book.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative based on the fact that the selected node always automatically scrolls in view.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    TreeView1: TTreeView;
    TreeView2: TTreeView;
    procedure TreeViewDragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer;
      State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
    procedure TreeViewEndDrag(Sender, Target: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure TreeViewMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  private
    FDragNode: TTreeNode;
    FNodeHeight: Integer;
  end;

...

procedure TForm1.TreeViewMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  with TTreeView(Sender) do
  begin
    FDragNode := GetNodeAt(X, Y);
    if FDragNode <> nil then
    begin
      Selected := FDragNode;
      with FDragNode.DisplayRect(False) do
        FNodeHeight := Bottom - Top;
      BeginDrag(False, Mouse.DragThreshold);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.TreeViewDragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer;
  State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
var
  Pt: TPoint;
  DropNode: TTreeNode;
begin
  Accept := Source is TTreeView;
  if Accept then
    with TTreeView(Source) do
    begin
      if Sender <> Source then
        Pt := ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos)
      else
        Pt := Point(X, Y);
      if Pt.Y < FNodeHeight then
        DropNode := Selected.GetPrevVisible
      else if Pt.Y > (ClientHeight - FNodeHeight) then
        DropNode := Selected.GetNextVisible
      else
        DropNode := GetNodeAt(Pt.X, Pt.Y);
      if DropNode <> nil then
        Selected := DropNode;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.TreeViewEndDrag(Sender, Target: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
var
  DropNode: TTreeNode;
begin
  with TTreeView(Sender) do
    if Target <> nil then
    begin
      DropNode := Selected;
      DropNode := Items.Insert(DropNode, '');
      DropNode.Assign(FDragNode);
      Selected := DropNode;
      Items.Delete(FDragNode);
    end
    else
      Selected := FDragNode;
end;
```

You *may* want to link the OnDragOver event handler to the parent of the TreeView too, which results in scrolling ánd dropping when the mouse is outside the TreeView. If you dó want the scrolling, but not the dropping when the mouse is outside the TreeView, then check `if Target = Sender` in the OnEndDrag event handler.

Comment: I'm curious as to how this performs in comparison to the timer based version. Any comments?

Comment: Yes, for I am curious too! The difference in functionality is that the scrolling in this version depends on mouse movement rather than time elapsing, which may result in no scrolling at all when it ís expected (i.e. when user doesn't move the mouse). As far as performance concerns: I will do some measuring.

Comment: I don't mean speed when I say performs. I mean the usability. It sounds like it would be a bit odd if you have to waggle the mouse to get it to scroll.

Comment: Furthermore, this scrolling isn't delayed (yet) which could make it hard to drop in the middle of the list. But delaying the scrolling would make the "not scrolling"-problem only worse. To be continued...

Comment: @David Well, I used this method for ListBoxes, but I change and start using your code. ;)

Comment: @David: 'Odd' isn't really the right word, for a lot of Windows controls behave like that (that is, they require the waggle). Still, I agree that it is not the ideal design...

Comment: @andreas which controls require a waggle?

Comment: @David: I can't find an example right now, but I remember the 'feeling' of having to waggle the cursor. However, you might be right -- maybe there aren't that many such controls. My 'feeling' might be induced by the fact that some controls (such as the Microsoft Word editor control) scroll *faster* if you waggle the cursor (and therefore I always do waggle it).

Comment: @andreas waggling to speed up sounds like a useful touch to add. How would you add it to my timer based approach? It sounds non trivial to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be complete, workarounds like in the other answers are not required anymore. Later versions have an option for this:

`TreeOptions.AutoOptions.toAutoScroll := True`