# Delphi TListview Scroll While dragging

Tags: delphi, tlistview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scroll TTreeView while dragging over/near the edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243193/scroll-ttreeview-while-dragging-over-near-the-edges)

I have a Tlistview with about 50 items in it, The Listview is configured for drag and drop which working fine if I want to drag a few items up  / down the visible listview, however the listview does not allow me to scroll either to the end or begining when dragging items so I can only drag items up or down the rows that are visible.

How can I make the listview scroll up  / Down while dragging?

Thanks

Colin

Comment: The duplicate question outlines how to do this for a tree view but that code can be trivially ported across to a list view or indeed any other control with vertical scrolling.

Comment: In fact I've just updated the answer at the duplicate control to include fully general code that will add auto-scroll whilst dragging for any `TWinControl` descendent.

Comment: @David I have tried your recommendation however I cannot get it to scroll the problem occurs @ if not InRange(Pos.X, 0, FControl.Width) then begin Exit End; It always seems to be out of range and exits? Colin

Comment: I've just tried it out on a TListView and it works fine. That line of code you quoted just checks that the cursor is within the horizontal bounds of the control. The way I have configured it, the cursor needs to be inside the control, but near the top or bottom.